# How to run Qt app compiled&linked with Qt 4.8.4 on a system with integrated Qt 4.8.6

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, qt, shared-library

I wrote an application using Qt 4.8.4. Now I purchased a new PC and installed Kubuntu 14.10 based on Qt 4.8.6.

To develop my application, I built Qt 4.8.4 from source using `make install` and that went successfully. But I get the following error at runtime:

```
Cannot mix incompatible qt library 0×40806 with this 0×40804.
```

Setting `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.4/lib` doesn't help.  (It was originally empty)

I tested the application on another PC with a **freshly installed Kubuntu and it runs**. No mixed conflicts! On there is the same QT 4.8.6 installed.

*Is there a way to run my application on my machine without rebuilding my program with the newly installed Qt 4.8.6 from source?*